# Busca em api local, react-native

Tags: react-native

Pessoal eu estou com uma api local no eclipse e estou usando o tomcat eu estou tentando usa-la com XMLHttpRequest no react-native e não estou conseguindo da sempre erro request.

```
onPressButtonAtualizarBanco=() => {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if (request.readyState !== 4) {
            return;
        }
        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log('success', request.responseText);
        } else {
            console.warn('error');
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/Restful/cliente/brinddata');
    request.send();
}
```

Os dados da api esta retornando em xml por isso estou usando o XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Qual erro? Especifique

Comment: Funcionou '-' e usei localmente!